# python count list item occurences and put result in list

Tags: python

I have a list like this

```
L=['d','f','d','c','c','f','d','f']
```

and i would like to count how many d,f and c occurences are in L and store the result like:

```
R=[['d',3],['f',3],['c',2]]
```

What is the best approch (algorithm) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach (algorithm), is to not do it yourself!

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L=['d','f','d','c','c','f','d','f']
>>> Counter(L)
Counter({'d': 3, 'f': 3, 'c': 2})
```

If you insist on a list:

```
>>> Counter(L).items()
[('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('f', 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel a dictionary would be better for this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L = ['d','f','d','c','c','f','d','f']
>>> Counter(L)
Counter({'d': 3, 'f': 3, 'c': 2})
```

However, if you're adamant about a list of lists:

```
>>> L=['d','f','d','c','c','f','d','f']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> var = Counter(L)
>>> [[key, value] for key, value in var.items()]
[['c', 2], ['d', 3], ['f', 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L=['d','f','d','c','c','f','d','f']
from collections import Counter
print Counter(L)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'d': 3, 'f': 3, 'c': 2})
```

You can use [`Counter.most_common`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method to get the result like this

```
print Counter(L).most_common()
```

**Output**

```
[('d', 3), ('f', 3), ('c', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on a sorted data

**Implementation**

```
from itertools import groupby
[[k,  len(list(v))] for k, v in groupby(sorted(L))]
```

**Output**

```
[['c', 2], ['d', 3], ['f', 3]]
```

**Performance Comparison**

```
    In [9]: L = [choice(ascii_letters) for _ in range(1000)]

    In [10]: %timeit [[k,  len(list(v))] for k, v in groupby(sorted(L))]
    1000 loops, best of 3: 271 us per loop

    In [11]: %timeit Counter(L).items()
    1000 loops, best of 3: 306 us per loop
```

*Note*

It should be noted that the overhead in the Counter Solution in hashing the data, overshoots the Sorting Complexity in `Tim's Sort`

Comment: Your first sample is wrong - you measure time of string creation. On my machine:list appreciation - 250 us; __Counter__ without __items()__  - 232 us; with __items__ - 239 us. List appreciation is the slowest

Comment: @volcano: I am failing to see, the string creation in the first sample :-)

Comment: Well, you cheated and changed your answer :). . Anyway, the result seems to be implementation-dependent. I've run it several time - pure __Counter__ always wins. I think the rule of the thumb is - If you have specific API to do something for you- do it that way; in most cases it will be more efficient